# IIS Server - HTTP Error 401.3 - Unauthorized

Tags: windows-7, iis, iis-7

I just installed IIS server for testing and I can't get it to work, it shows 40.3 Error.

> HTTP Error 401.3 - Unauthorized You do not have permission to view
>   this directory or page because of the access control list (ACL)
>   configuration or encryption settings for this resource on the Web
>   server.

```
Module              IIS Web Core
Notification        AuthenticateRequest
Handler             StaticFile
Error Code          0x80070005
Requested URL       http://localhost:8051/
Physical Path       C:\Users\Steve\Documents\ASP\1
Logon Method        Anonymous
Logon User          Anonymous
```

How can I fix this?

Comment: Better move your website files to `C:\Inetpub\wwwroot\any_folder`

Answer (score 1):

If its a development machine just give everyone read/write/execute privileges on that directory. That's pretty much dropping a nuke on the user privileges and def not something to do in a production environment.  But has worked for me in the past on my development / testing boxes.